# Adding thousands separator "˙" to a float number

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I'm working with a range of number from 0.00 to 9999.99 .
I need to add the "˙" thousands separator, so `1300,00` should became `1˙300,00`.
NSNumberFormatter use "," as separator so it isn't good for me.

I tried using

```
func formatNumber (i: Float) -> String {
    var counter = 0
    var correctedNumber = ""

    if i > 999 {
        for char in "\(i)".characters {
            if counter == 1 {
                correctedNumber += "˙" + "\(char)"
            } else {
                correctedNumber += "\(char)"
            }

            counter++
        }
    } else {
        correctedNumber = "\(i)"
    }

    return correctedNumber
}
```

but it can't format decimal numbers.

What's the correct way to do that?

Comment: Can't you use the `groupingSeparator` property of `NSNumberFormatter` to configure it to use your chosen separator?

Comment: Yeah! I didn't know the existence of .groupingSeparator, that's great! Thank you!

Comment: Usually you shouldn't tamper with those values. They are automatically set to the locale (language) set by the user. If the user's language has commas as grouping separators, don't put different characters there, it will only confuse users. Maybe just settings a specific `.locale`, e.g. `formatter.locale  = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")` would be better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to properly configure the `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.groupingSeparator = "˙"
formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
```

Testing

```
formatter.stringFromNumber(1300) // "1˙300,00"
```

Comment: Wow, that's good! I didn't know the existence of `.groupingSeparator`, that's great! Just a curiosity: if I need to format a number with thousand separator between first and second digit (for instance XXX˙X), can I do that still using NSNumberFormatter or it work only with group of tre digits?

Comment: @Matte.Car: You can set the size of the group using the `groupingSize` property. E.g. with `formatter.groupingSize = 2` you'll get this `"13˙00,00"`. And with `formatter.groupingSize = 1` you'll get this `"1˙3˙0˙0,00"`.

Comment: But if I need to work with different size groups, for instance 100˙0 (group of three digit than a single) can I do that using NSNumberFormatter?

Comment: @Matte.Car: I don't think so. But if you can describe how to calculate the size of the groups (size of the first group, size of the second one etc...), I think I can define a function to format the number as you need.

Comment: I've already wrote a function to do weird format, if NSNumberFormatter were able to do that, I would have lost a lot of time!

Answer (score 2):

While setting a specific `decimalSeparator` and `groupingSeparator` certainly works, it's not the best way to do what you want.

`NSNumberFormatter` always chooses the format according to the current locale. If the locale is set to English (usually `en-US`), then decimal separator will be a `,` and grouping separator a `.`.

This way if a user in USA opens the app, they will see number formatted correctly for them. If a user in Europe opens the app, they will also see numbers formatted correctly (as specified by their device settings).

If you really want the app to have one specific number format, you can just set the language explicitly, e.g:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")
```